# Asp.Net Core HttpPost API for Upload Image results in Could not get any response

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to build a new API in ASP.Net Core 2.0 to upload a single file from javascript. I write the asp.net core code and try to test it from Postman, but I receive the message "Could not get any response"

Down, the API class code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory;
using System.IO;
using SDN.Portal.Components;
using TinifyAPI;

namespace SDN.Portal.Controllers
{
    public class ApiController : BaseController
    {
        private IHostingEnvironment _env;

        public ApiController([FromServices] IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings,
                                [FromServices] IMemoryCache memoryCache) : base(appSettings, memoryCache)
        {

        }


        [HttpPost("api/upload")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UploadImage(IFormFile image)
        {
            _env = Startup._env;
            var pathProvider = new PathProvider(_env);

            var pathImage = $"./images/post/{image.FileName}.{image.ContentType}";
            var newPath = pathProvider.MapPath(pathImage);

            if (image.Length > 0)
            {
                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(newPath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await image.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                }
            }

            return Ok(new { status = true, message = "Upload Ok", link = newPath }) ;
        }

    }
}
```

and down, the response from Postman
[Erro from postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/haU3i.png)

Comment: Are you sure it's https and not http? localhost for me is usually http. Also shows your startup to see how you're routing the controllers.

Comment: Yes, the https works well, I have in the same projects, API with HttpGet and work's fine too.

Follow the startup.cs code:

Comment: What's the exact error you are receiving ? Have you checked your debug output to see if the request is ever even hitting the API ?

Answer (score 0):

The startup.cs code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite;
using SDN.Core;
using System.Globalization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions;

namespace SDN.Portal
{
    public class AppSettings
    {
        public string SiteUrl { get; set; }
        public string CheckoutUrl { get; set; }
        public string StorageUrl { get; set; }

        public bool Analytics { get; set; }

        public string ValidationMessage { get; set; }
        public string SucessMessage { get; set; }
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

        public string MailSender { get; set; }

        public string SmtpServer { get; set; }
        public string SmtpPort { get; set; }
        public string SmtpUserName { get; set; }
        public string SmtpUserAPIKey { get; set; }

        public string RecaptchaSecret { get; set; }

        public string SiteLocale { get; set; }

        public int PageSize { get; set; }
        public double CacheTime { get; set; }

        public string SelectPlanURL { get; set; }
        public string AdvertiseURL { get; set; }
        public string BaseCentralURL { get; set; }

        public string TinifyKey { get; set; }

    }

    public class Startup
    {
        internal readonly AppSettings _appSettings;
        internal static IHostingEnvironment _env;
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            _env = env;
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
               .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
               .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
               .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();

            //Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));

            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                // Set a short timeout for easy testing.
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                // Make the session cookie essential
                //options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            });

            services.AddMvc(options =>
            {
                options.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
            });

            SDN.Core.Common.Configuration.ConnectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseBrowserLink();
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error/{0}");
                var options = new RewriteOptions().AddRedirectToWww().AddRedirectToHttps(StatusCodes.Status301MovedPermanently);

                app.UseRewriter(options);
                app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
            }

            var locale = "pt-BR";
            RequestLocalizationOptions localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions
            {
                SupportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo> { new CultureInfo(locale) },
                SupportedUICultures = new List<CultureInfo> { new CultureInfo(locale) },
                DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(locale)
            };

            app.UseSession();

            app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                //routes.IgnoreRoute("{file}.js");
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }

        public class IgnoreRouteMiddleware
        {

            private readonly RequestDelegate next;

            // You can inject a dependency here that gives you access
            // to your ignored route configuration.
            public IgnoreRouteMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
            {
                this.next = next;
            }

            public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
            {
                if (context.Request.Path.HasValue && (
                    context.Request.Path.Value.Contains(".ico") 
                    || context.Request.Path.Value.Contains(".xml") 
                    || context.Request.Path.Value.Contains(".png") 
                    || context.Request.Path.Value.Contains(".txt")
                    || context.Request.Path.Value.Contains(".htm")
                    || context.Request.Path.Value.Contains(".js")
                    || context.Request.Path.Value.Contains(".jpg")
                    || context.Request.Path.Value.Contains(".gif")
                    || context.Request.Path.Value.Contains(".css")
                    || context.Request.Path.Value.Contains(".scss")
                    || context.Request.Path.Value.Contains(".json")
                    ))
                {

                    context.Response.StatusCode = 404;

                    //Console.WriteLine("Ignored!");

                    return;
                }

                await next.Invoke(context);
            }
        }
    }
}
```